# How do I insert the round code in echo?

Tags: php, html, decimal

I want the number to have 2 decimal places because it shows all the decimal numbers. Here's my code:

```
<?php 
    $add=mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT SUM(fil), SUM(math), SUM(aralp), 
    SUM(mapeh), SUM(esp), SUM(mtb), (SUM(total)/5), SUM(mps) from `grade1`');

    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($add))
    {
        $mark=$row1['SUM(fil)'];
        $mark3=$row1['SUM(math)'];
        $mark4=$row1['SUM(aralp)'];
        $mark5=$row1['SUM(esp)'];
        $mark6=$row1['SUM(mapeh)'];
        $mark7=$row1['SUM(mtb)'];
        $mark9=$row1['(SUM(total)/5)'];
        $mark10=$row1['SUM(mps)'];
    }
?>
```

How do I insert the `round(2)` here?

```
<?php
    echo "<th></th><th>AVERAGE</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark3</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark4</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark5</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark6</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark7</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark9</th>";
    echo "<th>$mark10</th>";
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you dont need a loop for retrieving one row

Comment: I am new to this. What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

This is it actually

```
echo "<th>".round($mark, 2)."</th>";
```

Now, I'll have to face another problem.